# Why isn't SQS an event source for lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda functions have a bunch of [event sources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html) but SQS ain't one.

Why is that? I would have thought it was a good fit.

Comment: 2018 update: SQS was demoed as an event source during the AWS Summit in San Francisco 4th of April and it will be added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 28 JUN 2018 [AWS Lambda Adds Amazon Simple Queue Service to Supported Event Sources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/).

Answer (score 2):

To some extent; yes I do agree with your view point.

But If you really think of difference between SQS and SNS is that (as John rightly pointed out) SQS is supposed to make things asynchronus... It is like a queue which can be consumed when needed. Queue to be consumed whenever suppose Agent is available.  SQS is to maintain workflows which can have lots of lag between different activities. For close to realtime operations SNS/Kinesis are better solutions.

If you want Lambda to be invoked; I think better architecture would be to send message to SNS and let Lambda get invoked.

Comment: Or, you'd need an outboard process consuming the queue and invoking the Lambda function *synchronously* at whatever level of peak concurrency is desired.  Synchronously, because that's the only way to determine concurrency from the outside.

Comment: I agree @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SQS is a queueing service, designed as a buffer for holding messages until they are consumed by an application. SQS is typically used where a **backlog** occurs prior to the consuming application.

AWS Lambda, however, is a highly parallel service that can run functions in parallel. Lambda functions are triggered by an **event**, such as uploading a file to Amazon S3 or receiving data via Amazon Kinesis.

I don't have a definite answer as to *why* Lambda cannot be triggered by SQS, but I'd guess it is because there is **no need** to do this. Instead of sending a message to Amazon SQS, **the originating application should simply invoke the AWS Lambda function directly**. This is a simpler process, with less moving parts.

There is a [default limit of 1000 concurrent Lambda functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html). If this is not enough, Lambda queues the requests and you can also request a limit increase.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Do we have any guarantees about queued request delivery? Especially when there is a high number of requests in relation to the concurrent function limit.

Comment: From [Lambda Function Concurrent Executions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html): "AWS Lambda automatically retries the throttled event for up to six hours, with delays between retries. "

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good blog post that shows you how to setup SQS as an event source for Lambda in code. Example in Terraform:

```
# Event source from SQS
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "event_source_mapping" {
  event_source_arn = "${var.terraform_queue_arn}"
  enabled          = true
  function_name    = "${aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.arn}"
  batch_size       = 1
}
```

https://medium.com/appetite-for-cloud-formation/setup-lambda-to-event-source-from-sqs-in-terraform-6187c5ac2df1