# Is it possible to create SQS as event source for LAMBDA in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am going through the AWS tutorial:
[Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon Simple Queue Service - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-example.html)

Steps:

1. Create the Execution Role. – OK
2. Create the Function – OK
3. Test the Function – OK
4. Create an Amazon SQS Queue -OK

The step that is failing is “Configure Event Source”:

```
aws lambda create-event-source-mapping --function-name AlexProcessSQSRecord  --batch-size 10  --event-source arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678901:AlexTrainingQueu
```

The error that I see is as follows:

```
aws: error: argument --starting-position is required
```

However, no value for starting-position fits

Also, there is a post in StackOverflow that states that it is not possible to use SQS as an event source for Lambda:

[Why isn't SQS an event source for lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317369/why-isnt-sqs-an-event-source-for-lambda)

So, why the Amazon tutorial suggests:

Using AWS Lambda with Amazon Simple Queue Service

Comment: Hi Alex, what do you mean by "no value for starting-position fits"? Do you get an error when you pass it in, or you're not sure what value to pass in? I'd assume that "LATEST" is what you'd want from the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html

Comment: What version of aws cli do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message even using `--event-source-arn`

Upgrading to latest `aws cli` solve it.

Example:

Lets have a sqs queue name `ingest` and lambda function `message-receiver`

```sh
aws lambda \
    create-event-source-mapping \
    --batch-size 1 \
    --event-source-arn arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:ingest \
    --function-name message-receiver
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use interface on console.

Open `lambda function` => click `Add trigger`, select SQS

Also, use `--event-source-arn` not `--event-source` (it is a mistake in the documentation).

Comment: @Alex: Could you try with `--event-source-arn` not `--event-source`

Comment: Yes, looks like an error on that documentation page. I've submitted Feedback with the correction.

Comment: @tuanVa - the same after your suggestion

Comment: @Alex Are you sure? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG04C.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYZbW.png

Comment: @JohnRotenstein did you get your correction published?

Comment: @Alex Yes, the documentation page has now been updated with the fix above.